# Can Conditional Execution or another technique drive the parameter values of another ItemReader in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-batch

I understand that Spring Batch has a Conditional Execution that can be configured to decide which step to go next based on the ExitStatus of the current step but...

1. what if I want my Spring Batch job to run a query which resultset I use to decide the value of a parameter in a query that I have in ItemReader is SpringBatch setup for that?
2. Or is Spring Batch framework going to "force" me to have a Processor and a Writer for that initial query?

If the answer to the second question is **yes**, how can it be handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thats quite easy, you can use a [TaskletStep](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#taskletStep) to run the query and use a "normal" Step (read: reader, writer, processors are optional) which uses some values provided by the TaskletStep.

To get the values from the first step to the latter, you can use [late-binding of job/step attributes](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#late-binding), see this [stackoverflow question for interstep communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117060/storing-in-jobexecutioncontext-from-tasklet-and-accessing-in-another-tasklet) too.

For a "normal" Step a ItemReader and a ItemWriter are set, the ItemProcessor is optional.