# Is there a spring batch "job" scope?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I just want to know if there is a "JOB" scope in spring batch, like the "STEP" scope ?
If there is not, should we develop our custom scope, or is there a better alternative ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you extend your question with more details about what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have created a dataHolder bean to share data between different steps of the Job. My job, could be executed asynchrounously by multiple threads, so for thread-safety requirements, i did want to create a dataHolder bean per each executed Job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally Spring Batch 3.0 supports now the `Job Scope` : [What's new in Spring Batch 3.0](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/whatsNew.html)

Answer (score 6):

A jira has been opened some times ago on the spring batch issues tracker regarding this issue:
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/BATCH-1701

A pull request has been submitted as well, hopefully it will be merge soon, because I have this use case too:
https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-batch/pull/41

There are multiple workarounds in the mean time, each with its drawback,
see this answer on stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8121102/470107

Comment: I think the third link the correct way to do it: you have a "Job execution scope", which is better than a "job" scope if you want to have each thread isolated with its own data

Answer (score 0):

if your dataHolder bean holds state you could try it with a proper [bean scope](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes) e.g. prototype

Comment: But with the prototype scope, each time i will reference my dataHolder bean from a job step, a new bean would be created ? Me, i would like to use the same dataHolder bean from all a given job's steps.

Comment: i am still not really sure about your usecase, but a simple threadsafe shared state could be accomplished with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: Thank you michael for your help, to resolve my problem, i finally create a dataHolderResolver Bean (Singleton), containing the method getDataHolder(int jobId) returning the DataHolder associated to the given jobId. I declared my dataHolder bean as a prototype, and i used the lookup-method spring feature on the dataHolderResolver bean, to get a new dataHolder reference, if it's not yet created and cached for a given jobId. But, i think that it will be usefull to have the 'job' scope in next version of Spring batch.