# "Step" or "Job" Scope for Spring-Batch beans?

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

I'm using Spring-Batch v3.0.0 for batch imports. There is a `StepScope` and a `JobScope`. How can I know which of them is appropriate?

For example, if I define a custom `ItemReader` or `ItemWriter` that should use a specific `EntityManager`, it could look like this:

```
@Bean
@Scope("step") //@Scope("job") //custom scope required to inject #jobParameters
public JpaItemWriter<T> jpaItemWriter(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaItemWriter<T> writer = new JpaItemWriter<T>();
    writer.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return writer;
}
```

But which scope is right here? And why?

Execution with `step` scope works, but I feel the itemWriters should maybe be of `job` scope so that they are not recreated on every step.

I tried switching `step` to `job`, but that throws following error:
 `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope 'job'`

Comment: how is `emf` wired? using `@Value`? which is its scope?
Also look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353570/is-there-a-spring-batch-job-scope?rq=1

Comment: `emf` is also a `@Bean` definition, without specific scope. Regarding your link to that issue: yes, it seems that the job scope was introduced exactly for what I'm trying. But switching from `step` to `job` scope is not working for me...

Comment: Why would this not be a singleton?  The Job scope really has a very small useful use case.  Most other scenarios should be either singleton or step (which is why we took so long to add it in the first place).

Comment: I need the non-singleton scope to inject `@Value("#{jobParameters[input]}")` (sorry, I should have written that).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Spring-Batch v3.0.1 you can use @JobScope

> Marking a @Bean as @JobScope is equivalent to marking it as @Scope(value="job", proxyMode=TARGET_CLASS)

Answer (score 3):

Got it: one has to provide the scope as a bean explicit within the `@Configuration` file.

```
@Bean
public JobScope jobScope() {
    return new JobScope();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in my version of spring batch. `JobScope is abstract and cannot be instantiated.` Of course, I don't seem to need it when using the `@JobScope` annotation, so maybe it was just a 3.0.0 thing.

Comment: I'm using `spring-batch` in context of `spring-boot-1.4.0`nowadays, and not using the `@Bean JobScope` anymore. So, probably this was just a legacy issue. You can now just use both `@StepScope` and `@JobScope` on your `Steps`. I think the problem in the past was the the `JobScope` bean has not been initialized by default. But it is now.