# How to configure dymanic name in spring batches

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have fifteen job configuration in my spring batch project. The jobs are been called from different source. That means I do not have control over the call.

Ten out of fifteen job perform the same task, therefore I want to create a single configuration file and execute all the ten jobs.

My question is :

Is it possible to dynamically change the job name in the configuration file.

Comment: Use 1 abstract bean definition for job skeleton and 10 concrete beans with different name, one for job. You might check for alias, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created one context file with all the similar job and another file with the common bean definitions. This has helped me in reducing a lot of code works.

Answer (score 1):

The answer may not be what you are expecting. But I used this technique for a similar situation (not for the batch jobs, though).

You may have multiple bean definitions, pointing to same Java Class and receiving a property value different for each definition. Based on the value of jobSource, you may want perform necessary action needed for that source.

```
<bean id="job1" class="your.job.class.Here">
    <property name="jobSource" value="source1" />
</bean>

<bean id="job2" class="your.job.class.Here">
    <property name="jobSource" value="source2" />
</bean>
```

Comment: user3714034: thanks for your efforts! Do you know any way by which I can change the jobname in the context file on the runtime?

Comment: Please check if following links help.

The one which shows how to get ExecutionContext:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117060/storing-in-jobexecutioncontext-from-tasklet-and-accessing-in-another-tasklet

The documentation that provides interface to enable job processing:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/EnableBatchProcessing.html