# Spring Batch-Read Ids from a file get the data for the Ids

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am using Spring batch solution for my project. I have a situation where I need to read ID's from a file and for those Ids I need to pull the data from the database, process it and then write it to an output file.

Currently I use a FlatFileItemReader to read the data from the file and then in the processor I collect them and for every thousand count (in clause has 1000 limitation) I hit the database to collect the data for those Ids and use a Writer to write the output.

But i somehow feel there should be a better way to do this. If I have access to the DB which I am hitting I could store these Ids in a temp table to join and get the output. But  I cannot do that. Is there anyway to connect the readers.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should design you job in two steps while passing output of step # 1 to step #2 OR by persisting output of step#1 to intermediate storage if that is going to simplify reader logic in step#2.

**STEP#1:** Consisting of a `FlatFileItemReader` -> Processor .

**STEP#2:** DB reader - > Processor -> Writer

Going by your problem description, it seems you can add a writer in **STEP#1** to write to temporary/intermediate table.

Also, it looks you don't need processor in **STEP#2**.

STEP#1 data can be passed to STEP#2 using `ExecutionContext`, [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117060/storing-in-jobexecutioncontext-from-tasklet-and-accessing-in-another-tasklet) and  [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32560700/spring-batch-pass-data-between-steps?rq=1)

Also, sentences like , **But I cannot do that** aren't helpful unless you add more explanation about why?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. "But I cannot do that"  means I have no write access to that database or I am not supposed to create any objects in the DB since it is not within our project limits.  So any other solution u suggest rather than creating an interim table.

Comment: so what is the issue? I guess , you need to directly pass data from step 1 to step 2 without persisting it. I have not implemented that logic but guess that passing data is possible as explained in those links.